# totalcmd like file manager which will show found files in one of panels

Tags: file-management, search

I'm looking for totalcmd like file manager (2 panels) which will show found files (totalcmd alt+F7) in one of panels so I can copy/move them to another panel. It would be fine if found files will be displayed with full path. Platforms: Windows and/or Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is already included in totalcmd and can be called from serach menu by clicking to "feed to listbox"